# Upright math in italic lemma

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, italic

I naively entered the following math-mode/text mix in a theorem environment, but the way LaTeX treats the parenthesis doesn't seem right. Especially upright math formulas in italic text parenthesis look strange, even though this is exactly how I would write it in regular text.
Also the parenthesis in the end seem weird in contrast to the big upright one in the formula.

Is this a problem in LaTeX that is supposed to be circumvented manually? If so, what is the best way to make this look more consistent?

```
\begin{conj}
  Let $a$ ($b$) be $3$ ($5$). (Recall that $c=\Big( \AImatrix(C) \lor \AIclause(C) \Big)$.)
\end{conj}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to distinguish between text parenthesis and math parenthesis. As you do. If it does not look good, you have to rewrite your sentence in order to get some text in front of the colon. You may want to try `\left(` instead of `\Big(`. BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX. In future, please show us complete compilable code. We don't know, what `\AImatrix` a.s.o. are.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do except rephrase the sentences to avoid most of the text-mode parentheses. For instance, you could write `Let $a$ and $b$ be $3$ and $5$, respectively. Recall that $c=\bigl( \AImatrix(C) \lor \AIclause(C)\bigr)$.` Note that I wouldn't use `\Big` for the outer parentheses, in large part because they end being visually overpowering; `\big` would seem to be more than adequate for the task. In fact, does one need the pair of outer parentheses in the expression that defines `$c$`?

Comment: Unfortunately, an italic font with upright parentheses is not available. I use `\textup(` and `\textup)` for parentheses in statements; coherence would require braces around `(` and `)`, but this is a case where “breaking the rules” is justified. Use normal size and not `\Big`; in any case, it should be `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`; try `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` if you want.

Comment: @Mico/@egreg: In some other context, `\Big` does make sense for the formula. Sorry, i guess i wasn't clear about that this is just an example.

Thanks for your answers, so i'll try to rewrite the sentences then.

Comment: I think, you might be interested in @cgnieder's package [embrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embrac). "The pack­age re­de­fines the com­mands `\emph` and `\tex­tit` so that paren­the­ses and square brack­ets are type­set in an up­right font in their ar­gu­ments."